# cakephp with url different from server to server

Tags: url, cakephp

this is my problem.
on my pc (wamp) if i click on a link that use an $id var, it goes to the right page and the link is already right (like (index.php/prenotation/1).
i uploaded my site to bytehost site, and if i click on the same link, it is wrong (index.php/prenotation) without the final $id.
I don't think it is something about the host type.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Does the rest of the page works fine? Are you expermineting other kinds of problems? Sounds like a routing problem, maybe mod_rewrite isn't set in this new server.

Comment: if i click on a link, the result is that I stay on the same page, because the $id miss.

Comment: Ok. But the css and image are working fine? Can you post the url of the site here? Despite of your id problem, does the links redirect you to the correct controllers? I need more information to help you with this problem!

Comment: yes it redirect to the right controller, prenotation/1 will be prenotation, so it stays on the same page.